# Fastest way to set highest order bit of rax register to lowest order bit in rdx register

Tags: assembly, optimization, bit-manipulation, x86-64, micro-optimization

This is my approach:

```
and rdx, 0x1
ror rdx, 1
or rax, rdx
```

But I think this is not very efficient. And I don't know if shift operations would be more cost efficient.

Comment: This assumes that the MSB of `rax` is cleared, is that specified?

Comment: @Jester I edited the example. Should be clear now.

Comment: Which instruction set extensions are you permitted to use?

Comment: @harold just realized that the `shr` is unnecessary. If the lowest order bit of `rdx` is 0 then rax will stay the same. Otherwise, its highest order bit will be set to 1.

Comment: So rdx can be destroyed? Or do you need it to be rotated like that? Do you have another free register?

Comment: try bt rax,63 then rcl rdx,1 if rest of the RDX is not required to be preserved. If rest of RDX needs to be preserved, then  btr rdx,0 then bt rax,63 then adc rdx,0

Comment: @phuclv `rdx` can be destroyed. Only goal is to set highest order bit in `rax` to it's lowest order bit

Comment: @fuz All the default instructions that are available for the intel x86-64 ISA - so everything from the manual. (I'm new to assembly so I don't know about any other "libraries"/ISA extensions).

Comment: @stht55 There are some later instruction set extensions like BMI providing useful additional instructions.  If you are not permitted to use them,

Comment: Intel's manual includes BMI1 / BMI2 extensions, but they're only supported on newer CPUs (e.g. Haswell and later for Intel).  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ for an instruction-set listing scraped from Intel's PDFs.  They're not library functions, they're real machine instructions that newer CPUs support.  For per-instruction performance numbers on various CPUs, see https://uops.info/, and [Agner Fog's guides](https://agner.org/optimize/) for how to understand latency vs. uops and ports.  Also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Do the rest of the bits in RAX matter?  Do they need to keep the same value and stay in the same position?  If not, `shrd rax, rdx, 1` does the job by shifting the low bit of RDX into the top of RAX.  (And also right-shifting the existing bits in RAX).  Or code also assumes that RAX's top bit is initially not set, as others have pointed out, so you should definitely edit the question to be clear about guaranteed pre-conditions and required post-conditions so we know which parts are intentional and which parts are bugs in our implementation, and what else might be allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 add rax,rax
 shld rdx, rax, 63
```

Msb of rax is first removed, then the concatenated sequence only contains the lsb of rdx and the 63 bits of rax, which are to be shifted left to `rdx`.

or

```
 add rax, rax
 shrd rax, rdx, 1
```

(This answer assumes, that the explanation in the question is right and the code is wrong -- since 'copying' a cleared bit over a set bit is not possible with that code.)

Comment: `shl rax, 1` should be equivalent to `add rax, rax` in time and size, and

Comment: @NateEldredge On Intel processors, 4 `add` instructions can be executed in parallel in 1 cycle while only 2 `shl` instruction can be executed. Both have the same latency. Thus, using `add` could be a bit better regarding the rest of the code (and possibly the use of hyper-threading). On AMD Zen processors, I do not expect any difference.

Comment: On AMD Zen+/Zen2, `shrd` is surprisingly slow since it takes 3 cycle per instruction (TP). This is mostly fixed in Zen3. As a result this code should be eventually slower (than the initial one) on such processors.

Comment: `shld`/`shrd` is also slow on some older Intel processors. It got fast from Sandy Bridge. https://uops.info/table.html?search=SHLD_IMMB%20(R64%2C%20R64%2C%20I8)&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_CON=on&cb_NHM=on&cb_SNB=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_doc=on&cb_base=on

Comment: It's possible to do `add rax,rax; shr edx, 1; rcr rax,1` sequence to get rid of the shld/shrd; AFAIK rotates with #imm == 1 are fast on most processors. Correctness over speed...

Answer (score 2):

If rdx can be destroyed then you don't need to mask it like that because the left shift will clear the remaining bits anyway

```
shl rdx, 63
or rax, rdx
```

*This assumes that the MSB of rax is cleared*, as [Jester said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057313/fastest-way-to-set-highest-order-bit-of-rax-register-to-lowest-order-bit-in-rdx#comment127321212_72057313)

Comment: Don't think that shifting rdx by 63 is the most efficient solution in terms of time/clk cycles.

Comment: @stht55 All processors since the 80386 have a barrel shifter, so all shifts take the same amount of time, regardless of shift amount.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the least significant bit of rdx is clear but the most significant bit in rax was already set.

Comment: @fuz ah yes. I didn't think about the title and just looked at the OP's code which also doesn't work for that case

Answer (score 1):

Rotate is as fast as shift on modern processors, but on older ones, it can be slow, so it's better to use shift if it can solve the problem.

If you can destroy `rdx`, I'm pretty sure that the following instruction sequence is the fastest on any x86_64 processor.

```
shl rdx, 63
or rax, rdx
```

Comment: rax has 64 bits so you would have to write `shl rdx, 63`